# Python: Dictionaries, How to copy and update the second copy?

Tags: python, dictionary

First of all, I need help formatting a dictionary into 3 sections;
I have attempted it by doing this

```
>>> d = {'A':{'Round1':[4,3,2,6,7]},{'Round2':[1,2,5,3,4]}}
```

But receive a syntax error.
Also, after I created the dictionary, how would I save it to another copy, then append more numbers per round(like round3) later on to the original dictionary.

Comment: I think your first line of code is un-formatted. Also there are a few grammar mistakes that can be changed to improve the quality of your question.

Comment: @SteveFest Posted an edit

Comment: looks like you need dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting without syntax error:

```
d = {
    'A': {
        'Round1': [4, 3, 2, 6, 7],
        'Round2': [1, 2, 5, 3, 4]
    }
}
```

Save it to another copy:

```
import copy
d2 = copy.deepcopy(d)
```

Append more rounds to the original dictionary:

```
d['A']['Round3'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print(d)  # {'A': {'Round1': [4, 3, 2, 6, 7], 'Round2': [1, 2, 5, 3, 4], 'Round3': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}}
print(d2) # {'A': {'Round1': [4, 3, 2, 6, 7], 'Round2': [1, 2, 5, 3, 4]}}
```

Append more sub-dictionaries:

```
d['B'] = {'Round1': [4, 3, 2, 6, 7], 'Round2': [1, 2, 5, 3, 4]}

# d = {
#     'A': {
#         'Round1': [4, 3, 2, 6, 7],
#         'Round2': [1, 2, 5, 3, 4],
#         'Round3': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
#     },
#     'B': {
#         'Round1': [4, 3, 2, 6, 7],
#         'Round2': [1, 2, 5, 3, 4]
#     }
# }
```

Append to an array in the dictionary:

```
d['A']['Round1'].append(8)

# d = {
#     'A': {
#         'Round1': [4, 3, 2, 6, 7, 8],
#         'Round2': [1, 2, 5, 3, 4],
#         'Round3': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
#     },
#     'B': {
#         'Round1': [4, 3, 2, 6, 7],
#         'Round2': [1, 2, 5, 3, 4]
#     }
# }
```

Comment: Could i add more dictionaries within that? Like 'B'

Comment: Sure: `d['B'] = {}`

Comment: but within the same format of the rounds? like `d = {
    'B': {
        'Round1': [4, 3, 2, 6, 7],
        'Round2': [1, 2, 5, 3, 4]
    }
}`

Comment: Like this: `d['B'] = { 'Round1': [4, 3, 2, 6, 7], 'Round2': [1, 2, 5, 3, 4] }`

Comment: But i cant put the key 'B', in the same dictionary as A?

Comment: I don't understand. What is your expected result?

Comment: Could i add all the keys in the same way u did A? so B and C, would be in the same format all INSIDE d? can you show me if so?

Comment: Finally, @aaron what if i want to append into an array in the dictionary round1, from user input?